# Rails 4 + Devise: How to write a test for Devise Reset Password without RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, minitest

For reasons outside of my control, I can't use RSpec for testing in my current project. I'm trying to test Devise Reset Password, and I can't seem to come up with something that works.

Here's what I have so far:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ResetPasswordTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:example)
  end

  test "reset user's password" do 
    old_password = @user.encrypted_password

    puts @user.inspect

    # This assertion works
    assert_difference('ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count', 1) do
      post user_password_path, user: {email: @user.email}
    end

    # puts @user.reset_password_token => nil
    # Not sure why this doesn't assign a reset password token to @user

    patch "/users/password", user: {
      reset_password_token: @user.reset_password_token, 
      password: "new-password", 
      password_confirmation: "new-password",
    }

    # I get a success here, but I'm not sure why, since reset password token is nil.
    assert_response :success

    # This assertion doesn't work. 
    assert_not_equal(@user.encrypted_password, old_password)
  end

end
```

I've added some comments above to where things don't seem to be working. Does anyone have an insight, or an idea about how better to test this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out that you need to reload the user upon sending the password reset email and when `put`ting the `/user/password` route. You also need to get the password token from the email as it is different from the one stored in the database.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ResetPasswordTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:example)
  end

  test "reset user's password" do 
    # store old encrypted password
    old_password = @user.encrypted_password

    # check to ensure mailer sends reset password email
    assert_difference('ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count', 1) do
      post user_password_path, user: {email: @user.email}
      assert_redirected_to new_user_session_path
    end

    # Get the email, and get the reset password token from it
    message = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[0].to_s
    rpt_index = message.index("reset_password_token")+"reset_password_token".length+1
    reset_password_token = message[rpt_index...message.index("\"", rpt_index)]

    # reload the user and ensure user.reset_password_token is present
    # NOTE: user.reset_password_token and the token pulled from the email
    # are DIFFERENT
    @user.reload
    assert_not_nil @user.reset_password_token

    # Ensure that a bad token won't reset the password
    put "/users/password", user: {
      reset_password_token: "bad reset token", 
      password: "new-password", 
      password_confirmation: "new-password",
    }

    assert_match "error", response.body
    assert_equal @user.encrypted_password, old_password

    # Valid password update
    put "/users/password", user: {
      reset_password_token: reset_password_token, 
      password: "new-password", 
      password_confirmation: "new-password",
    }

    # After password update, signed in and redirected to root path
    assert_redirected_to root_path

    # Reload user and ensure that the password is updated.
    @user.reload
    assert_not_equal(@user.encrypted_password, old_password)
  end

end
```

Comment: How do you run this test? and in which directory you place the test file ?

Comment: @MinaZaki I put this test in `/test/integration/` and it just runs with the normal test suite with `rake test`.

Comment: … or by running `rake test:integration`

Answer (score 16):

Devise tests the `PasswordsController` internally.  I wanted to test my `PasswordsController` with extra functionality and went to [Devise's controller tests](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/controllers/passwords_controller_test.rb) for help in building tests for Devise's default functionality, then adding assertions for my new functionality into the test case.

As noted in other answers, you must obtain the `reset_password_token`.  Instead of parsing a delivered email as in another solution here, you could obtain the token in the same way as Devise:

```
setup do
  request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  @user = users(:user_that_is_defined_in_fixture)
  @reset_password_token  = @user.send_reset_password_instructions
end
```

Check out Devise's solution for the `PasswordControllerTest`:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/controllers/passwords_controller_test.rb.

Comment: @Bryan Ash Thanks for the edit! I forgot that answers could be sorted!

Comment: This should be accepted answer, because it's better to directly get the token instead of email parsing.

Answer (score 7):

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'User' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:new_password) { 'Passw0rd!' }

  it 'reset password' do
    visit '/'

    click_link 'Forgot password?'
    fill_in 'E-mail', with: user.email

    expect do
      click_button 'Send me reset password instructions'
    end.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count).by(1)

    expect(unread_emails_for(user.email)).to be_present
    open_email(user.email, with_subject: 'Reset password instructions')
    click_first_link_in_email
    fill_in 'New password', with: new_password
    fill_in 'Confirm new password', with: new_password
    click_button 'Change password'

    expect(page).to have_notice 'Your password has changed'
    click_link 'Logout'

    fill_in 'E-mail', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: new_password

    click_button 'Sign in'
    expect(page).to have_notice 'Wellcome!'
  end
end
```

This code require email_spec and FactoryGirl gems.

Comment: Really cool approach! But if you use Capybara, email_spec won't help you. Use https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/capybara-email instead